# Exit notice page fails decoding

Tags: relays

On any chromium based browser the exit notice on my DirPort gets "err_failed_content_decoding"

On Firefox, it works fine

My relay runs Tor 0.3.5.8 on Ubuntu 18.10

**EDIT**: On the update to 0.3.5.8 from 0.3.5.7, there is now an SSL error on chrome (err_ssl_protocol_error). Still no issue on Firefox, just chrome. For some reason, chrome is enforce https

Comment: Check if Tor 0.4.0.1 helps with this problem: [Tor no longer sets Content-Type when sending compressed results](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/28100).

Comment: Is v4 out of beta yet?

Comment: Not yet. However you could take a look to see whether it is fixed. If not, please report the bug.

Comment: Wouldn't that give me the "not recommended" flag? That was why I stopped running beta in the first place

Comment: Oh I forgot that. You could try running another instance of Tor.